# mysqldump with --no-tablespaces on InnoDB with index?

Tags: innodb, mysqldump, myisam, tablespaces

Does mysqldump --no-tablespaces dumps index files of InnoDB?
I know that MyIsam uses separate index files *.MYI for index. So if one uses mysqldump with --no-tablespaces, does that mean index is not exported?

Answer (score 4):

"Tablespaces" are for clumping tables into a single `.ibd`.  The mysqldump options relating to that control whether to output the DDL statements such as `CREATE TABLESPACE`.

`mysqldump` does not dump the *contents* of indexes, regardless of Engine.  It *does* dump the definitions of the indexes.  When reloading, the indexes will be recreated.  Yes, MyISAM has a separate file for indexes while InnoDB includes the indexes in the same "tablespace" file; but the locations of indexes is an implementation detail that does not matter when dumping and reloading tables.

If you have not explicitly created any "tablespaces", ignore options relating to them.  (Very few people use tablespaces.)

Comment: Is a restored index really the same index? This is like one of those Star Trek transporter ethical questions, right?

Comment: Equivalent to rebuilding the index.  Same functionality, same process.  If a transponder did not faithfully rebuild the item, then it would be useless.  Same as creating a "new" index for the table.